# Cannot Use Dropbox on macOS after Using VPN (Lantern)

Tags: macos, proxy, dropbox

In China, I use VPN to connect to Dropbox, Google, Youtube... Now, I have come to the USA, but I found I cannot use Dropbox without VPN I used in China (Google, Youtube are ok)

I cannot open www.dropbox.com, and cannot connect to Dropbox via the Dropbox software on my macOS. The VPN I used in China is Lantern (it is not an a.d.)

I try to find the solutions, like resetting the network of macOS, but it didn't work. Could you help me with this problem? I would like to provide any information if you need. Really thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, finally I solve this problem. It was caused by VPN. Because it modifies my host file of macOS. I delete all lines about `Dropbox` in the host file, and then I succeed :-)